# Set columns at the same height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have an issue about to set height of col2 and col3 at 70% respect of 100% col1, and col4 and col5 at 30%, I tried set this height's with some styles but so far I have had no luck.

Some recommendation?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 border">
          <h1>Col1</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" style="height:70%">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col border">
                  <h1>Col2</h1>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col border">
                  <h1>Col3</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12" style="height:30%">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col border">
                  <h1>Col4</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col border">
                  <h1>Col5</h1>
                  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/UOsmGB But the last row of the second column might extend because of the large text.

Comment: Oh I see, but in this case I need that both principal columns had the same height independently who has more text than other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the column heights to a fixed height (either a percentage or 100% of its parent), then there’s no way for the setup to expand if, in the future, your Col 5 content is larger than you expect.

If you need more flexibility, you could setup the right-side column as a flex container and set the upper row to expand while the lower row stays the same. You won’t get an exact 70/30 split, but it will have a similar visual effect with the ability to have the lower row container more information without overflowing the space.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 border" style="padding: 0 15px">
            <h1>Col1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-9">
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: 100%;">
                <div class="row flex-grow-1">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 border">
                        <h1>Col2</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 border">
                        <h1>Col3</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 border">
                        <h1>Col4</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 border">
                        <h1>Col5</h1>
                        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, sunt.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid bg-info mt-1 pt-5">
    <p class="text-center">next section</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fill-height {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 border">
      <h1>Col1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row fill-height">
        <div class="col-12" style="height:70%">
          <div class="row fill-height">
            <div class="col border fill-height">
              <h1>Col2</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col border fill-height">
              <h1>Col3</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" style="height:30%">
          <div class="row fill-height">
            <div class="col border fill-height">
              <h1>Col4</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col border fill-height">
              <h1>Col5</h1>
              <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```